# How to use API routes in NextJS 13

Tags: reactjs, middleware, next.js13

When using Express I used to store  user like `request.user` :

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"; 
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler"; 
import User from "../models/userModel.js";

const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;
  token = req.cookies.jwt;
  if (token) {
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.userId).select("-password");
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(401);
      throw new Error("Not authorized , invalid token");
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("Not authorized , no token");
  }
});

export { protect };

And I was able to get the current user like this : 

const createPost = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { content, image } = req.body;
  const user = req.user;
```

But how to do this using  NextJS 13 API routes and middleware and also how to use cookies.
New to NextJS so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Next.js, you can use the cookies extension on NextRequest and NextResponse to read and manipulate cookies. Here's how you can do it:

First, you need to import cookies from next/headers:

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
```

Then, you can get a cookie like this:

```
const cookieStore = cookies()
const token = cookieStore.get('token')
```

To set a cookie, you need to return a new Response using the Set-Cookie header:

```
return new Response('Hello, Next.js!', {
  status: 200,
  headers: { 'Set-Cookie': `token=${token}` },
})
```

You can also use the NextRequest object to read cookies:

```
export async function GET(request) {
  const token = request.cookies.get('token')
}
```

For incoming requests, cookies comes with the following methods: get, getAll, set, and delete cookies. You can check for the existence of a cookie with has or remove all cookies with clear.

For outgoing responses, cookies have the following methods get, getAll, set, and delete.

Here's an example of how you can use these methods:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  let cookie = request.cookies.get('nextjs')
  console.log(cookie) // => { name: 'nextjs', value: 'fast', Path: '/' }
  const allCookies = request.cookies.getAll()
  console.log(allCookies) // => [{ name: 'nextjs', value: 'fast' }]

  request.cookies.has('nextjs') // => true
  request.cookies.delete('nextjs')
  request.cookies.has('nextjs') // => false

  const response = NextResponse.next()
  response.cookies.set('vercel', 'fast')
  response.cookies.set({
    name: 'vercel',
    value: 'fast',
    path: '/',
  })
  cookie = response.cookies.get('vercel')
  console.log(cookie) // => { name: 'vercel', value: 'fast', Path: '/' }

  return response
}
```

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow, CyberJ.

It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since at least *eight* of of your answers yesterday appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.